# Deploying a wasm - webassembly + hosted - error HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I did the following steps in my development machine windows 10

1. I installed the web hosting bundle - ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle 6.0
2. added an app pool and pointed to No Managed Code

3)[image]

4. I went to the IIS -> default web site -> Add Application -> Blazor App ->

[image]

5)Press Ok and I browsed the site http://localhost/BlazorApp and i get the following error.

[image]

6)The project is the boiler plate I deployed. I used visual studio 2022 and created a wasm + hosted application and then publised it to a folder and used that folder to point it to physical path in the iis

> What am i Missing?

Comment: There's many different causes for this error, but the physical path doesn't look right.  Seems like it should be pointing to inetpub... something like "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot"  Are you publishing this to the same machine that the Visual Studio runs in?  Does it run properly in the VS?

Comment: just to clarify a bit, it looks like you are pointing to VS's internal localhost folder...  by default your machine's IIS server would be pointing to inetpub.

Comment: I had to install iis-url rewrite module, then this error is no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install iis-url rewrite module, then this error is no more.
to install this

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite